# Change the background color of matched strings when doing find-and-replace

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

This is not a fundamental question, but it puzzles me. In doing a Find & Replace for some string in a notebook, the matched string is highlighted temporarily with some background color (green for me). Does someone know how to change the background color of the matched string? I would like to make it easier to identify.

**note added**

As many notebook elements have editable colors through Option Inspector, I thought that the color of a searched string could also be easily modifiable, probably too optimistic...

Thank's for the proposal of m_goldberg. A user-defined Find and higlight function would be far sufficient !

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Are you asking to subvert the built-in find-and-replace dialog or would you a accept a user-defined find-and-highligt function? Trying for the first would open a big can of nasty worms even if feasible (and I'm skeptical about its feasibility). The second is doable.

Comment: Do you want a temporarily change (like the default) or a permanent one?

Comment: @belisarius, I would prefer a permanent change. Thank's

Comment: for @everybody: there is a `Find.nb` on the front end system resources directory that may (not sure) help

Comment: @belisarius. I have examined the file **Find.nb** but at first glance, I could not find anything related to my problem. Maybe m_goldberg is right in saying that it is a non-modifiable internal property... Don't waste your time on it, I can live with that as it is !

Comment: I'm not wasting my time. It's called _sport_  :)

Comment: @belisarius. So many times it happened to me that, while doing a string search in a long and complicated expression, I couldn't see where the highlighted found string was located... Maybe need other glasses :-)